# How to connect visio shapes on page by passing the name of the shape to connect to from a variable?

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I am trying to connect the visio shapes in my drawing. I am using autoconnect. I have a loop that goes thru all the visio shapes in my drawing. It goes thru the values in my range and compares them to the shape name, if the shape name matches then it should connect to the shape who has the name stored in the offset (0, 2) of my range variable but I’m having problems passing the variable to the script. If I do a debug print for the variable that stores the shape names to connect to then it prints to screen the names of the shapes that the current shape in the loop needs to connect to. So it has the correct data.

Here is some of the code.

```
 Dim conns As Range

    Dim connto_str As String

    Dim ew As Excel.Workbook

    Set ew = wbkInst.ActiveWorkbook

    Dim conns As Range

    Dim cel As Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet


    For Each ws In ew.Sheets

        Set conns = ws.Range("j3:j22")


        For Each cel In conns


            With cel

                c = cel.Value


                connto_str = cel.Offset(0, 2).Value  


            End With


            For Each node In ActivePage.Shapes

                If node.Name = c Then

                node.AutoConnect connto_str, visAutoConnectDirNone


                'Debug.Print connto_str


                Else

                End If


            Next node

        Next cel


    Next ws
```

I need to be able to pass the content of the variable this statement.

```
node.AutoConnect connto_str, visAutoConnectDirNone
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`connto_str` needs to be an Object of Type Shape, not just the name of a Shape.
If you know on which page the shape is on you can use page.Shapes("ShapeName") to get a reference to the shape.
Source :
[Microsoft Docs Visio.Shape.AutoConnect Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.autoconnect)
[Microsoft Docs Shapes.Item Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shapes.item)

```
Dim ew As Excel.Workbook
Set ew = wbkInst.ActiveWorkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ew.WorkSheets 'use .WorkSheets, to avoid selecting other Sheet-Types like diagrams

    Dim conns As Range
    Set conns = ws.Range("j3:j22")

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In conns.cells
        Dim c as String
        c = cel.Value

        Dim connto_str As String
        connto_str = cel.Offset(0, 2).Value

        Dim conno_shp as Shape
        Set conno_shp = activePage.Shapes(conno_shp)

        Dim node as Shape
        Set node = ActivePage.Shapes(c)

        node.AutoConnect connto_shp, visAutoConnectDirNone

    Next cel
Next ws
```

You also forgot to declare/dim node.

I cleaned up your code a bit, although it is still quite fragile, since you assume so know the name of the Shape, which actually may change as you drop it.

Your Variable-Names are a bit difficult to understand, you probably should change them to something more readable, your successor will thank you. Use names that are self-explanatory.

Why not give each shape you drop an entry into the ShapeSheet under the User-Section, something like `User.NetworkDiagrammName`.

Comment: @Thanks for always helping me out. I did declare node. I forgot to write it. Again Thank You.

Comment: Thanks Hi i tried the code it didn't work. I think i was pretty close. Now that I know that the variable for the shape to connect to has to be an object of type shape. How do I pass the value of the offset  to that variable like the one you created "connto_shp" ? Please be patient with me I'm new to visio and vba have read a lot but clearly need to learn a lot more. My worksheets are one for each node or shape  and on column k they have the node name corresponding to the worksheet and  on the offset the name of the shape for the node they need to connect to. Again Thanks